# Within a monorepo (using Turborepo) is it possible to start dev and Storybook (lives in a child package) with a single command?

Tags: storybook, monorepo, turborepo

In a dev environment instead of spinning up my monorepo first with `npm run dev` (which uses Turborepo) then cd'ing into a package where Storybook lives and executing `npm run storybook`, is there a way to spin up both with one command (ie. `npm run dev`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.
I'd recommend you to use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) for that. You can write a separate run config that uses concurrently:

- first, install concurrently

```bash
npm i -D concurrently
```

- introduce a new script configuration in your `package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "...",
    "start": "concurrently -n dev,storybook -c yellow,green 'npm run dev' 'cd .storybook && npm run storybook dev -p 6006'"
  }
}
```

- you should then be able to run `npm start`.